# If $G$ has only one subgroup of order $n$, then that Subgroup is Normal

Tags: finite-groups

How can I show that if some group $G$ has only one subgroup $K$ of order $n$, then $K$ is a normal subgroup?
Would that mean that it only has one subgroup total? If so then I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Hint: conjugation preserves order.

Comment: Isn't that the definition?

Comment: @Tony: No, that's not the definition, it is the observation you can use to see that conjugation gives another group of order $n$, hence you can apply your hypothesis that there is only one such group.  "Would that mean..." No, there can be other groups with different orders.  For example, $\mathbb Z_{32}$ has only one subgroup of order $2$, but it has a few other subgroups with different orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To flesh out Alex Youcis's suggestion, we recall that a subgroup $K < G$ is normal iff for every $g \in G$, $gKg^{-1} = K$. But always we have that $gKg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of order $n$ (since conjugation is an automorphism). So it is another subgroup of order $n$. But there is only one, $K$, so $gKg^{-1}=K$ for all $g$.

Comment: I suppose you mean $gKg^{-1} = K$, not $H$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes, thanks!